# Terraform - do not update resource if variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have this resource in a AWS Terraform implementation. It's an AWS Lambda function alias which i plan to use in a Ci/CD pipeline.

```
resource "aws_lambda_alias" "alias_dev" {
  name          = "dev"
  description   = "dev"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.hello_terraform.arn
  function_version = aws_lambda_function.hello_terraform.version
}
```

I want this resource to NOT get updated (i want to ignore function_version attribute) if i pass a certain value for a input variable when using apply.
For example, if i set variable deploybranch = develop :

```
terraform apply -auto-approve -input=false -var="deploybranch=develop"
```

I try doing that using using lifecycle

```
 lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "function_version"
    ]
  }
```

however , I'm not able to tie the lifecycle to the input variable.

Is this possible - using lifecycle or other technique?

Comment: You could try using the ternary operator but not sure if function version can be left as `null` in that case: `function_version = var.deploybranch == "develop" ? null : aws_lambda_function.hello_terraform.version`

Comment: the version cannot be null - should have the same values as before apply

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you need the function alias in that case at all for the develop branch?

Comment: There are 2 aliases - one for production and one for devel. One needs to get updated the other one to remain unchanged.

Comment: For the same Lambda function?

Comment: yes , same function, different versions, 2 aliases used by devel and production api gateway routes

Comment: I don't see another way except providing the version to the dev alias explicitly. But I might be missing something.

Comment: there is a workaround using bash and aws cli scripting but i would prefer to have a terraform solution - thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Btw : Is there a way to read the aws_lambda_function.hello_terraform.version before doing the apply ?  This  function_version = var.deploybranch == "production" ? "7" : aws_lambda_function.hello_terraform.version works - however i need to replace the "7" with the version that is in state before "apply"

Comment: As in fetch the previous version dynamically? I don't think that's possible unfortunately. If it's numbered, you could always try the simple math of `${aws_lambda_function.hello_terraform.version}  - 1`, but not sure if that would work.